# TypeScript Vuetify project - use Two.js Text to render multiline text

Tags: typescript, text, vuetify.js, two.js

I have a Vue/Vuetify project and I would like to use [Two.js Text](https://two.js.org/#two-text) to create multiline text.  I would like something like this

```
const t1 = new Two.Text("Text must &#13;&#10; be upright 2\u{1D7B9}", 50, 80, {});
t1.size = 12;
t1.noStroke();
t1.fill = "#000";
(t1 as any).leading = 50;
(t1 as any).id = "mytext";
(t1 as any).className = "myClass";
<twoInstance>.layers[LAYER.foregroundText].add(t1);
```

Where `&#13;&#10;` would indicate a line break. I'm rendering with SVG and the HTML entry that comes up is

```
<g id="two-124" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 487 487)" opacity="1">
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 50 80)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="12" 
line-height="50" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" 
alignment-baseline="middle" font-style="normal" 
font-weight="500" text-decoration="none" 
fill="#000" stroke="undefined" stroke-width="undefined" 
opacity="1" class="" visibility="visible" id="mytext">
Text must &amp;#13;&amp;#10; be upright 2</text></g>
```

So it is not multiline text.

I'm accessing some of the internal variables of Two.js [Text](https://github.com/jonobr1/two.js/blob/dev/src/text.js) in typescript (and perhaps I shouldn't) and so I'm setting thinks like `id`, `className` (appears not to work) and `leading`. I was hoping that I would be able to give this an `id` and then use CSS to process the `<text...> </text>` tag/string and add the line break, but no luck.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
#mytext {
  font: italic 40px serif;
  fill: red;
  rotate: 90;
  <something here to process the text?>
}
</style>
```

I was hoping to use the CSS to inject/process a [content area](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/text.html#TermContentArea) in the text tag and then use [auto wrapped text](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/text.html#TextLayoutAuto) (Links might be old - but that is what I was thinking). Again no luck.

I think the SVG gets in the way. I would ultimately like the text before and after centered.  Any thoughts on this challenge? Thanks!